# Как переименовать конфигурационную папку в python django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

```
MySite
  **MySite**
    settings.py
    __init.py__
```

на

```
MySite
  **config**
    settings.py
    _init.py_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пожалуйста, не переименовывайте проект, если вы уже создали его!**

Это не просто "конфигурационная" папка, а корневая директория проекта. Django создает не только файловую структуру данных, но и переменные окружения, которые вам также придется изменить, иначе Django не сможет запустить проект.

Если вы хотите, можете сделать следующим образом:

> следующие команды для ubuntu

1. Создайте папку MySite `cd MySite`
2. Создайте django-проект с именем config в папке MySite `django-admin startproject config MySite`

Почитайте больше о структуре приложений в django в официальной документации

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113789/discussion-on-answer-by-sergey-salamatov----).